# Regex capturing : get the whole match in a capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't get this capture to work as I would like :

My aim is to capture in a string the length of the first capture group :

```
var regex = /(_)?;([\w]+);([\w]+);/;
var string = "____;foo;bar;";
var matches = regex.exec(string);

console.log(matches); // outputs  ["_;foo;bar;", "_", "foo", "bar"]
```

As you can see, `matches[1]` contains the capturing group for undescores, but gives me the matched character, not all underscores. What i expect would be this result :

```
["_;foo;bar;", "_____", "foo", "bar"]
```

Is there a way to achieve this with a regex ? I would prefer avoid splitting the string with `;` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pattern like this:

```
/(_*);(\w+);(\w+);/
```

Which will give you:

```
["_____;foo;bar;", "_____", "foo", "bar"]
```

This pattern will match the following sequence:

- zero or more underscores, captured in group 1
- a semicolon
- one or more word characters, captured in group 2
- a semicolon
- one or more word characters, captured in group 3
- a semicolon